# Water valve to Ice maker stuck on

Tags: water, ice-maker, overflow

I have an 18 year old GE Side-by-side refrigerator/freezer with built in filter and water dispenser.  Recently we woke up one morning to water pouring out of the ice-maker onto the kitchen floor.  I shut off the water valve, but could still hear the water valve solenoid energized.  While cleaning up the mess. I lifted the arm of the ice-maker.  Sometime within the next hour, the hum from the solenoid stopped.  I'm thinking if the solenoid was stuck open, it would not have hummed as if energized.  So therefore I'm thinking whatever energizes the solenoid is the culprit.  What energizes the water solenoid?  The ice-maker?  Should I replace the ice-maker first, or the dual solenoid?  Neither is cheap, but the solenoid is cheaper than the ice-maker.  I just think it's the ice-make that has the problem.

Comment: Do you have the feeling that an 18 year old fridge is going to last much longer? Is it worth pouring any money into it?

Comment: Replace the ice maker.. It energizes the solenoid.  I had solenoid wouldn't open and replaced that first.  Still didn't open.  Exception to control might be if fridge has digital door controls, but ours (GE) the ice maker determined when the solenoid opened.  It's hard to troubleshoot with a meter because you have to figure out when fill is.

Comment: Since you could hear a hum or buzz I would guess that the control relay contacts stuck closed on the control board. At that age it may be worth the expense to replace the solenoid along with the board unless you have the ability to find the relay on the board and replace that.

Comment: Instead of a relay, I think you'll find its a cam switch in the ice maker assembly.